# Signal Detector (Field Strength Meter)

Tags: transistors, rf, diodes, signal

Hello I have attached a circuit of a Field Strength Meter that I came up with, my target frequency is around 500Mhz.

I was wondering if a design like this will even be able to tune to 500Mhz.
I am also wondering if I can swap the Ammeter with a current amplifier and then connect that to an LED instead to show the presence of the target frequency.

If there is something horribly wrong with this idea, please do tell.

[image]

Picture of a transistor based current amplifier that I was going to connect instead of the Ammeter.

[image]

Note: sorry these are not BC547 transistors but 2N2222A

Comment: I tweaked your images a bit to remove the whitespace.  A few users here have a pet peeve about too-large pictures :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that is horribly wrong that your transistors won't start conducting until the voltage at base reaches 1.3V. And that's a lot. You'll need to use either opamp with dual supply or a germanium transistor connected to a silicon one as a Sziklai pair.

EDIT: You can stay with your original circuit, just add some bias to the capacitor: connect the upper capacitor leg to the central point of a 10k:0.9k voltage divider, and connect the divider to +12 and ground.

Comment: Thanks for the response, are you referring to the actual transistor models on the second picture? I forgot to update it, I'm actually using 2 2N2222A transistors, I don't know if that'll still cause the same problem. Thanks

Comment: I am referring to _any non-germanium transistor_.

Comment: Could you recommend me a germanium and silicon transistor that may work for the type of circuit I am trying to build?

Comment: I've just edited the answer...

Comment: Having a bit of difficulty visualizing that, do you mind drawing a quick rough sketch? Thanks.

Comment: 900 Ohm parallel to the capacitor, the point where the diode connects to the cap to +12 through a 10k resistor. The idea is to keep the potential on the base of the transistor at 1.1V, just little below the voltage it opens.